# How to connect Android device to digital camera through USB?

Tags: android, usb

I am making a demo application in which i want to communicate a canon digital camera to Android device through USB through below through Android developer site i have created a min class i have write following code not sure may be it is working or not plz help guide me how to communicate digital camera to Android device?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html`

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class USBMainclass  extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent =new Intent();
        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    }
}
```

and in Android manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.USBCommunication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name=".USBMainclass">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" /> 
  </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i just want to Application detect digital camera through this code plz help..

Answer (score 0):

This way the device has to be connected when you start your activity. If you connect the camera after you started your app, it won't do anything.

Comment: How can i get information about the digital device means how can i get information from the digital camera to the application ?

Comment: You should read the link you posted from android developers more carefully.. Everything's there you need to know for the beginning.